# UNIX time, response always one minute off (faster/less) PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

We have a time and attendance portal, in which the employees apps need to display a countdown to when their shift starts (ex:employees shift is 9-5, when they open their app at 8:50, the server will give a response of 10 minutes, and the app will start the countdown {9:59, 9:58....etc})

We store all times in utc and use PHP functions to convert to the local times.

It was all fine and dandy until last week we started noticing that the response is always one minute off (so for the example above, would display 9:00 minutes remaining, etc) . regardless of the times of the shift or the difference of the shift start time.

***following is the server side logic:***

```
$fields['total_elapsed_time'] = $current_time - strtotime($first_check_in_timestamp);
$fields['current_time'] = $current_time;
```

***following is the app logic:***

````
```if currentTime < startTime {

                            self.isUserHaveShiftIn2Hours = true
                            let endDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(startTime))
                            self.totalWorkingSeconds = Double(self.getNumberOfSeconds(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate))
                            self.startTheCountDownForShift()

                        }```

`let startTime = response.result.value!.shift_start_time`
`let startDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(currentTime))`
`let currentTime = response.result.value!.current_time`
````

thanks!~

Comment: What's the second code block? If it's some kind of JavaScript preprocessor to produce client-side code, such code will of course run with the browser's clock.

Comment: thats the code run on the app (ios)
we do most of the heavy lifting server side (for calculations and such) but as the app has to display a "live countdown", thats the local logic to take the unix time and process accordingly. It was working for 6 months, all of a sudden last week (with no change to our code structure) its always 1 minute less..?